# How to change column values after transpose?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, transpose

Before I do a transpose, I have this:

```
grouped_and_summed.columns.values

array(['IDRSSD', 'RCFD3531', 'RCFD3532', 'RCFD3533', 'RCFD3534',
       'RCFD3535', 'RCFD3536', 'RCFD3537', 'RCFD3541', 'RCFD3543',
       'RCFD3545', 'RCFD3546', 'RCFD3547', 'RCFD3548', 'RCFDF610',
       'RCFDF614', 'RCFDF615', 'RCFDF616', 'RCFDF617', 'RCFDF618',
       'RCFDF624', 'RCFDF632', 'RCFDF633', 'RCFDF634', 'RCFDF635',
       'RCFDF636', 'RCFDF639', 'RCFDF640', 'RCFDF641', 'RCFDF642',
       'RCFDF643', 'RCFDF644', 'RCFDF645', 'RCFDF646', 'RCFDF647',
       'RCFDF648', 'RCFDF649', 'RCFDF650', 'RCFDF651', 'RCFDF652',
       'RCFDF653', 'RCFDF654', 'RCFDF655', 'RCFDF656', 'RCFDF657',
       'RCFDF658', 'RCFDF659', 'RCFDF660', 'RCFDF790', 'RCFDG299',
       'RCFDG332', 'RCFDG333', 'RCFDG334', 'RCFDG335', 'RCFDG379',
       'RCFDG380', 'RCFDG381', 'RCFDG382', 'RCFDG383', 'RCFDG384',
       'RCFDG385', 'RCFDG386', 'RCFDG387', 'RCFDG388', 'RCFDG651',
       'RCFDG652', 'RCFDHT62', 'RCFDHT62', 'RCFDHT63', 'RCFDHT63',
       'RCFDHT64', 'RCFDHT64', 'RCFDHT65', 'RCFDHT65', 'RCFDHT65',
       'RCFDHT66', 'RCFDHT66', 'RCFDHT67', 'RCFDHT67', 'RCFDHT68',
       'RCFDHT68', 'RCFDK197', 'RCFDK198', 'RCFDK199', 'RCFDK200',
       'RCFDK210', 'RCFDK211', 'RCFN3542', 'RCFN3543', 'RCON3531',
       'RCON3532', 'RCON3533', 'RCON3534', 'RCON3535', 'RCON3536',
       'RCON3537', 'RCON3541', 'RCON3543', 'RCON3545', 'RCON3546',
       'RCON3547', 'RCON3548', 'RCONF604', 'RCONF605', 'RCONF606',
       'RCONF607', 'RCONF611', 'RCONF612', 'RCONF613', 'RCONF614',
       'RCONF615', 'RCONF616', 'RCONF617', 'RCONF618', 'RCONF624',
       'RCONF625', 'RCONF626', 'RCONF627', 'RCONF628', 'RCONF629',
       'RCONF630', 'RCONF631', 'RCONF632', 'RCONF633', 'RCONF634',
       'RCONF635', 'RCONF636', 'RCONF639', 'RCONF640', 'RCONF641',
       'RCONF642', 'RCONF643', 'RCONF644', 'RCONF645', 'RCONF646',
       'RCONF647', 'RCONF648', 'RCONF649', 'RCONF650', 'RCONF651',
       'RCONF652', 'RCONF653', 'RCONF654', 'RCONF655', 'RCONF656',
       'RCONF657', 'RCONF658', 'RCONF659', 'RCONF660', 'RCONG299',
       'RCONG332', 'RCONG333', 'RCONG334', 'RCONG335', 'RCONG379',
       'RCONG380', 'RCONG381', 'RCONG382', 'RCONG383', 'RCONG384',
       'RCONG385', 'RCONG386', 'RCONG387', 'RCONG388', 'RCONG651',
       'RCONG652', 'RCONHT62', 'RCONHT62', 'RCONHT63', 'RCONHT63',
       'RCONHT64', 'RCONHT64', 'RCONHT65', 'RCONHT65', 'RCONHT65',
       'RCONHT66', 'RCONHT66', 'RCONHT67', 'RCONHT67', 'RCONHT68',
       'RCONHT68', 'RCONK197', 'RCONK198', 'RCONK199', 'RCONK200',
       'RCONK210', 'RCONK211', 'TEXTF655', 'TEXTF656', 'TEXTF657',
       'TEXTF658', 'TEXTF659', 'TEXTF660', 'Unnamed: 115_level_0',
       'Unnamed: 133_level_0', 'Unnamed: 139_level_0',
       'Unnamed: 20_level_0', 'Unnamed: 87_level_0'], dtype=object)
```

After I do a transpose, I get this:

```
df_final.columns.values

array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
       34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
       51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67,
       68, 69, 70, 71, 72], dtype=int64)
```

Is there some way to eliminate the numbers as column names and use row #1 as column names?

```
                              0           1           2           3   \
qyear                     2001Q1      2001Q2      2001Q3      2001Q4   
IDRSSD                7431574609  7440938099  7481396211  7503578925   
RCFD3531                       0           0           0           0   
RCFD3532                       0           0           0           0   
RCFD3533                       0           0           0           0   
                         ...         ...         ...         ...   
Unnamed: 115_level_0           0           0           0           0   
Unnamed: 133_level_0           0           0           0           0   
Unnamed: 139_level_0           0           0           0           0   
Unnamed: 20_level_0            0           0           0           0   
Unnamed: 87_level_0            0           0           0           0
```

So, instead of 0, 1, 2, 3, my column names could be: `2001Q1      2001Q2      2001Q3      2001Q4`

Comment: df.columns = df.iloc[0,:]

Comment: `df.columns = df.iloc[0]` should do the job, No?